# write 2 object is BigInteger to file

Tags: object, biginteger

I created a button to save two BigInteger numbers to file, I wrote code as below, but when I click the button "save test", it can't write, anyone can give me any advice?

```
public final static BigInteger numberN = new BigInteger("17855404456822874936847712749012221703363767319600747738346509047988764141076203590602575545059230348630206930110136685391297486715740834967023383072460701006180246289301165056178499131397684281330821144935962852141623402858240677770202677489833679398319826337183170013049969533314399531024754572058094731892694381452545462801033432474024224220241635573572538943432828608673126747833227351200161776312900643626121058023519446087845640534470254939863451117935546083448482346472288049441087336233290409696349030267736371540043446170340719650007973597139760511408444411001327893735548336735821557222262768663537785969181");

public final static BigInteger numberE = new BigInteger("3674911");

private void savetestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    File file=new File("E:\testghikey.txt");

    key a = new key();
    a.setName("Number N:");
    a.setNumber(numberN);

    key b = new key();
    b.setName("Number E");
    b.setNumber(numberE);

    try {

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oOT = new ObjectOutputStream(f); 
        oOT.writeObject(a); // Ghi  Object là đối tượng a xuống file
        oOT.writeObject(b);

        oOT.close();
        f.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not write the data to file "+ file.getName(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}

public class key implements Serializable {

    private String Name;
    private BigInteger Number;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public BigInteger getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }

    public void setNumber(BigInteger Number) {
        this.Number = Number;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I think it is exception error
...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI.paint(MetalTabbedPaneUI.java:803)
 at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI.update(MetalTabbedPaneUI.java:724)